# Is there a way to traverse a possibly-self-containing object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, traversal

I want to descend an object in Javascript looking for a specific string. Unfortunately, this object is built in such a way that it'd be impossible to simply use the source and Ctrl-F for that string, and it's also built in such a way that recursive functions trying to descend it risk getting trapped inside of it forever.

Basically, this object contains itself. Not just once, but in very many areas. I cannot simply say "exclude these keys", as the object is obfuscated and therefore we'd be here all day listing keys, and once we were done we wouldn't have looked at all the data.
As well, I need to be able to descend `__proto__` and `prototype`, as useful strings are hidden in there too. (But only for functions and objects.)

While I'd prefer something along the lines of `findStuff(object, /string/ig)`, that may be hard, so any function that simply has areas clearly marked that the control flow falls to once it's found specific objects (function, string, etc.)

Thank you, and sorry for such a pain in the butt question.

---

Edit: In case it helps, I'm trying to traverse a compiled Construct2 runtime object. I'm not going to post the full thing here as it's not going to fit in any pastebin no matter how forgiving, and also I don't want to accidentally post resources I don't have the permission to provide. (Don't worry though, I'm not trying to pirate it myself, I'm simply trying to figure out some user-facing functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a WeakSet to keep track of the objects that were already traversed:

```
 function traverseOnce(obj, cb) {
   const visited = new WeakSet();
   (function traverse(obj) {
     for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
       if(typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
          if(visited.has(value)) continue;
          visited.add(value);
          cb(value);
          traverse(value);
       }
      }
   })(obj);
 }
```

Through the WeakSet you got O(1) lookup time, and are also sure that this will never leak.

Usable as:

```
 const nested = { other: { a: 1 } };
 nested.self = nested;

 traverseOnce(nested, console.log);
 // nested: { other, self }
 // other: { a: 1 }
```

---

You could also use a Symbol to flag traversed objects, for that replace `new WeakSet()` with `Symbol()`, `visited.has(value)` with `value[visited]` and `visuted.add(value)` with `value[visited] = true;`

Comment: Used the `WeakSet` one simply because while the Symbol idea is extremely smart, it does modify the state of every object traversed, which is not great. Thanks!

Comment: "Wether that is "better" has to be determined in your usecase." - I'd argue the (Weak)Set approach is superior in all cases, because all the cleanup you need is just exiting the function, with no downside to it that I can see.

Comment: @amadan It keekps my thinking. If the function exits, the `WeakSet` hast to be gc'ed, while the symbol is quite lightweight. On the other hand, I assume that the flag will be kept on the objects, meaning that their size increases slightly and the hidden class has to be changed when the flag gets added. Thats probably premature optimization though

Comment: @JonasWilms Wouldn't a `delete visited;` at the end of traverseOnce fix all of that for the WeakMap?

Comment: @no_boot_device well the garbage collector does kick in nevertheless. I guess I'm overthinking it. "it does modify the state of every object traversed" ... you got a point there. I guess I should flip my answer

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're traversing a potentially cyclical object, keeping a memo of already traversed objects and breaking if you've seen the current object before is a standard technique. You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a list of objects you have recursed into, and then check each new object against that list.

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    bar: 1
  },
  one: 1,
  jaz: {
    hello: {
      x: 1
    }
  }
};

data.bar = data.foo;
data.foo.foo = data.foo;
data.jaz.hello.foo = data;

function search_for_1() {
  const seen = [];
  search(data);

  function search(object) {
    Object.values(object).forEach(value => {
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        if (seen.includes(value)) {
          console.log("Seen this already");
        } else {
          seen.push(value);
          search(value);
        }
      } else {
        if (value === 1) {
          console.log("Found 1");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

search_for_1();
```

Comment: I'd say that a `WeakSet` lookup is far more performant than an array search, wether that can be used depends on the environment though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel There are libraries for this kind of stuff.

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) for all our data processing. It's very powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how it would work for your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const traverse = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ key, value, parent }) => {
    // do something here
  },
  breakFn: ({ isCircular }) => isCircular === true
})(data);

const circular = { name: 'Max', age: 5, sex: undefined, details: { color: 'black', breed: undefined } };
circular.sex = circular;
circular.details.breed = circular;

console.log(traverse(circular));
/* =>
 [ [ 'details', 'breed' ],
   [ 'details', 'color' ],
   [ 'details' ],
   [ 'sex' ],
   [ 'age' ],
   [ 'name' ] ]
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)